# ¿Por qué el pdf que inserto no puedo verlo en el navegador de Android?

Tags: php, html, html5

Estoy intentando visualizar un pdf que tengo insertado en una base de datos mysql pero cuando lo leo y pongo en un iframe no se me muestra, cabe resaltar que esto solo sucede en Android porque si accedo desde una navegador de pc funciona perfectamente.

```html
<?php
    $pagina = explode("/",$_GET['views']);
    $band = false;
    if (isset($pagina[1])) {
        require_once "./controladores/checadorControlador.php";

        $ins_checador = new checadorControlador();
        
        $datos_checador = $ins_checador->verificar_datos_controlador($pagina[1]);

        if ($datos_checador ->rowCount() == 1) {
            $campos = $datos_checador -> fetch();
            $band = true;                        
        } else {
            echo '<script>
                Swal.fire({
                    title: "Ocurrió un error inesperado",
                    text: "El folio de la inspección no existe",
                    type: "error",
                    confirmButtonText: "Aceptar"
                });
            </script>';
        }
    }
?>

<div class="col">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <?php if ($band == true) { ?>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <embed class="embed-responsive-item" src="<?php echo 'data:application/pdf;base64,'.base64_encode($campos['inspecciones_pdf']) ?>" type="application/pdf">
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el valor que contiene la variable `$campos['inspecciones_pdf']`?

Comment: el contenido del pdf que extraigo de la base de datos

Comment: Es necesario saber el valor exacto de la variable para poder darte una respuesta. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y agregar dicha info en la misma. Dicho sea de paso ¿Cual es el navegador que usas en Android?

Comment: ya modifique el archivo para que vean toda la información, el valor de $campos['inspecciones_pdf'] viene de la base de datos de un campo tipo longblob